# Asp.net Page Counter : Store number in MySql Database

Tags: asp.net, sql, mysql

I've been searching the web for some good page hit counters.  I'd like to create a page hit counter asp.net page that keeps its values stored in a MySql Database under a row called 'PageCounter'.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most users don't care about how many times your page has been hit. That is why you see so few page hit counters these days. Why not just implement Google Analytics? You'll get far more valuable and comprehensive information that way. E.g., where are the users coming from, how long did they stay on the page, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Don't re-invent the wheel when there are plenty of free-wheels available.

[SiteMeter.com](http://www.sitemeter.com/)
[Freelogs.com](http://freelogs.com/)
[FreeStatscounter](http://www.freestatscounter.com/)

And zillions [more](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site+counter&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3MOZA_enUS334US346&ie=UTF-8)